# Is where a way we can integrate google dialogflow chat bot with our WebApps?

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot

Is where a way we can integrate google dialogflow chat bot with our WebApps?

I would like to create a chat bot and integrate in our webapp, so that when user type something on that page, that would reply with data stored in DB.

Please suggest if it can be done and steps. Or any other easy integration and chat bot design can be done.

I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API which you can use to integrate dialogflow chatbot in webapps

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api

Above link shows you how to interact with an agent by using the REST API using the client libraries.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview

Answer (score 1):

If you want to integrate with your own backend (to store or provide responses) a very popular approach is to use the DialogFlow Fulfillment.

- create a DialogFlow Agent
- configure the Webhook URL with your application/service implementing the webhook or use the inline capabilities (Cloud Functions for Firebase)

In terms of integrating on your web site (or web application) you have various options:

- DialogFlow web widget (for testing the integration only)
- use a Web plugin like Kommunicate or Botcopy
- build your own web widget, indeed possible with the Google api (see other answer)

Answer (score 0):

The Dialogflow app of https://board.support/dialogflow should work fine. You have the full source code and the license allows you to edit it.

In your case, you may need to contact the author for a custom license due it looks like you want to integrate it into an app that is sold/shared publicly.

Disclaimer: I work for Support Board